# frequency of each element in array

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to delete the duplicate value and print the count of each element. But I didn't get the correct answer. How to delete only the duplicate value and print the count? Here is my code

```java
public class RemoveArray {

    public static int[] delete(int[] arr, int x) {
        int[] sarr = new int[arr.length - 1];
        int j = x;

        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i != j) {
                sarr[k] = arr[i];
                k++;

            }
        }

        return sarr;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 8, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    int x = j;
                    count++;
                    arr = delete(arr, x);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }

}
```

I need output as

```
2
4
1
1
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(new int[]{ 1, 2, 8, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 }).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting())).values().forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing an element and not updating j accoridngly.

To fix your code, try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class removearray {

    static int[] delete(int arr[], int x) {
        int sarr[] = new int[arr.length - 1];
        int j = x;
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i != j) {
                sarr[k] = arr[i];
                k++;

            }
        }
        return sarr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 8, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    int x = j;
                    count = count + 1;
                    arr = delete(arr, x);
                    j--;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `Map` to count unique elements.

```java
public class Main {

    public static int[] removeDuplicatesAndSetCount(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            map.put(arr[i], map.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0) + 1);

        return map.values().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 8, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeDuplicatesAndSetCount(arr)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of 
`for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) res[j++] = map.get(arr[i]);`
You should do something like
`for (Integer i: map.keySet()) res[j++] = map.get(i);`
Otherwise, you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Yep, I can see your point. This is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a Map, I quickly wrote a beginner friendly way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 8, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1};

    //Find out min and max number in array
    int min = 100, max = 0;
    for (int k : arr) {
        if (k < min) min = k;
        if (k > max) max = k;
    }

    //Count elements
    int count = 0;
    int[] countArr = new int[max - min + 1];
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        for (int k : arr) {
            if (k == i) count++;
        }
        countArr[i - min] = count;
        count = 0;
    }

    //Print elements
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number " + i + " exists " + countArr[i-min] + " times");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
int[] ret = IntStream.of(arr)
        .boxed() // so you can use a "int" Array
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) //returns a Map from the number to its count
        .values() //all the "counts"
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()) //from long to int
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ret));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

**Way 1: Need extra calculation**

- sort array.
- iterate the sorted array. count each element frequency, print, or store frequency in an array.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,8,3,2,2,2,1};
Arrays.sort(arr);

int count = 0;
int prev = arr[0];
for(int a : arr) {
    if(a != prev) {
        System.out.println(count);
        //reset count
        count = 1;
        prev = a;
        
    }else {
        count++;
    }   
}
//this will print the last element count
System.out.println(count);
```

**Way 2: Need extra Memory**

- Using the sorted map's key, trace if a key exists or not
- If exist then update the key's count.
- Else put the new key with count 1.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,8,3,2,2,2,1,8};
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> sm = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int i : arr) {
    if(sm.containsKey(i)) {
        int count = sm.get(i);
        count++;
        sm.put(i, count);
    }else {
        sm.put(i, 1);
    }
}

Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> s = sm.entrySet();


Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> i = s.iterator();


while (i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry)i.next();

   
    int value = (int)m.getValue();

    System.out.println(value);
}
```

To get unique value array, create a new array put your value there during iteration.